# Open and close a connection to a PLC very frequently using pyads

Tags: python, flask, plc

So I have a flask app which will serve the status of some module being managed by a PLC. I will get very frequent GET requests on my app(~every 1 sec) and with each GET call, I'll have to fetch the status from the PLC. I am using [pyads](https://github.com/stlehmann/pyads) to connect to a PLC. The way they connect to a PLC is shown in the basic usage:

```
import pyads

# connect to plc and open connection
plc = pyads.Connection('127.0.0.1.1.1', pyads.PORT_SPS1)
plc.open()

# read int value by name
i = plc.read_by_name("GVL.int_val")

# write int value by name
plc.write_by_name("GVL.int_val", i)

# close connection
plc.close()
```

So my question is, should I open and close the connection to PLC inside the view function of the GET call or should I open a connection to the PLC when I create the app and just keep using that connection throughout the app? which is better?

Also I cannot really understand what kind of connection does the pyads package open with the PLC? Is it a TCP connection?

Comment: It is an extension to TCP.  If you are connection once a second, then it really doesn't matter whether you open and close.  If it's convenient to keep it open, then do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's a TCP connection as I gathered from [here](https://github.com/stlehmann/pyads/blob/fc7733d4d12b64bfb03384313ff54304e5c3ace8/pyads/testserver.py) and [here](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcadscommon/html/tcadscommon_intro.htm&id=)
Since Pyads is just a wrapper around underlying TwinCAT it uses the same underlying protocols as used by TwinCAT.

As I see TwinCAT [documentation](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcsample_vb/html/tcadsnet_vb_sample01.htm&id=), the sample library does not actively close the connection each time. So I believe you can connect once and keep the connection open.